# EPUB Score catching

Tags: javascript, xml, html, epub, adobe-indesign

I created an EPUB through Adobe InDesign CC. After exporting the project to EPUB i extracted the file so that I can insert a (html, javascript) page for the exercises. Could somebody please help how can I manage to throw a value from the epub (probably the score) to a website if online and store the value(score) inside the epub when offline.

```
<form action="#" method="post">
    <section id="1" epub:type="item">
            <p>1. smile - smiled <label id="checker" style="color:red"></label></p>
            <input type="radio" id="myRadio" name="c1" value="1" />
            <label>YES</label>
            <input type="radio" id="myRadio" name="c1" value="0" />
            <label>NO</label><br/>                 
    </section>
    <section id="2" epub:type="item">
            <p>2. dance - danced <label id="checker2" style="color:red"></label></p>
            <input type="radio" id="myRadio2" name="c2" value="1" />
            <label>YES</label>
            <input type="radio" id="myRadio2" name="c2" value="0" />
            <label>NO</label><br/>    
    </section>
    <section id="3" epub:type="item">
            <p>3. rise - rised <label id="checker3" style="color:red"></label></p>
            <input type="radio" id="myRadio3" name="c3" value="1" />
            <label>YES</label>
            <input type="radio" id="myRadio3" name="c3" value="0" />
            <label>NO</label><br/>   
    </section>
    </div>

</form>
```

Heres the javascript:

```
temp = 0;
if (getRadioVal( document.getElementById('demoForm'), 'c1' ) === "1") {
    temp = temp + 1;    
} else{
    document.getElementById('checker').innerHTML = "| wrong";
}

if (getRadioVal( document.getElementById('demoForm'), 'c2' ) === "1") {
    temp = temp + 1;
} else{
    document.getElementById('checker2').innerHTML = "| wrong";
}
if (getRadioVal( document.getElementById('demoForm'), 'c3' ) === "0") {
    temp = temp + 1;
} else{
    document.getElementById('checker3').innerHTML = "| wrong";
}

document.getElementById("score").innerHTML = temp;
```

Answer (score 1):

This question has been discussed in some Adobe Forum and the answer seems like you can't: https://forums.adobe.com/thread/1939249